# How do I pass a fraction to python as an exponent in order to calculate the nth root of an integer?

Tags: python, math, fractions

I'm attempting to write a simple python script that will calculate the squareroot of a number. heres the code i've come up with and it works. but i would like to learn how to use fractional exponents instead.

```
var1 = input('Please enter number:')
var1 = int(var1)

var2 = var1**(.5)
print(var2)
```

thanks for the help

Comment: You mean you get exponent input in the form of string 1/4 etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use fractional exponents with the help of `fractions` module.

In this module there is a class `Fraction` which works similar to our inbuilt `int` class.
Here is a link to the documentation of the class - http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html (just go through its first few examples to understand how it works. It is very simple.)

Heres the code that worked for me -

```
from fractions import Fraction  
var1 = input('Please enter number:')  
var1 = Fraction(var1)  
expo = Fraction('1/2')           //put your fractional exponent here  
var2 = var1**expo  
print var2
```

Comment: The best thing about using the class Fraction is that it does not matter whether the input (var1) is of type int, float, fraction, decimal or a string (a proper string), the above code snippet would always work.

Comment: `Fraction(1, 243)**Fraction(1, 5)` produces `0.3333333`, though, not `Fraction(1, 3)`

Answer (score 6):

```
numerator, denominator = [float(s) for s in raw_input().strip().split("/")]
print 2 ** (numerator/denominator)
```

I [strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) whitespace from the input, [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it into parts, then convert the parts to numbers with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

This will fail if the input isn't in fractional form. To check and behave appropriately...

```
line = raw_input().strip()
if "/" in line:
    numerator, denominator = [float(s) for s in line.split("/")]
    exponent = numerator/denominator
else:
    exponent = float(line)

print 2 ** exponent
```

If you had tried using `2 ** (1/2)` and it had failed, that is because `1` and `2` are integers, so Python 2 uses integer division and ignores the fractional part. You could fix this by typing `1.0/2` into your script or `input()`.

Comment: or you could use `exponent = numerator/(float(denominator))` rather than forcing the odd "1.0/2" input.